# Un-deleting your own answer counts as an undelete vote, but deleting it doesn't

Tags: bug, voting, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

On meta, I've deleted and then undeleted [this post of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/118018/revisions).

The votes tab on the account page does not list any deletion votes, but *does* list the undelete:

[image]

Is this because the undelete null-ifys the delete on the same post, or is this a bug?

Comment: Smells like a bug!

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I had that feeling as well... re-tagged accordingly!

Comment: I **suspect** that this has something to do with the fact that your *vote* to delete your own answer is binding, while voting to undelete generally isn't.

Comment: Voting to undelete your own answer is just as binding as voting to delete it.